# UI has been changed?

Tags: discussion, style

I have just noticed that the menu has been improved:

[image: Menu]

Are there other improvements, if any?

Answer (score 5):

Whether or not you consider a design choice is an improvement is up to you. That said, see the [Stacks GitHub repo](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks)* releases section, and specifically [the changelog for each release](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/releases).

That specific change was made [in Stacks release v2.3.0](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/releases/tag/v2.3.0). (It's the change labeled Important in purple text)

---

*Stacks is the design system Stack Exchange uses for the SE network.